# Difficulty allocating dynamic URLs to pages from database

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a large number of mostly static pages which I've put into a database. I'm trying to retrieve these and dynamically generate a URL (similar to this: http://railscasts.com/episodes/117-semi-static-pages-revised. My model:

```
 class Page < ActiveRecord::Base

validates_uniqueness_of :permalink

  def to_param
    permalink
  end
end
```

Pages Controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_page, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /pages
  # GET /pages.json
  def index
    @pages = Page.all
  end

  # GET /pages/1
  # GET /pages/1.json
  def show
    @page = Page.find_by_permalink!(params[:id])
  end

  # GET /pages/new
  def new
    @page = Page.new
  end

  # GET /pages/1/edit
  def edit
    @page = Page.find_by_permalink!(params[:id])
  end

  # POST /pages
  # POST /pages.json
  def create
    @page = Page.new(page_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @page.save
        format.html { redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @page }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /pages/1
  # PATCH/PUT /pages/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @page.update(page_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @page, notice: 'Page was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @page }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @page.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /pages/1
  # DELETE /pages/1.json
  def destroy
    @page.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to pages_url, notice: 'Page was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_page
      @page = Page.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def page_params
      params.require(:page).permit(:name, :permalink, :content)
    end
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :pages, except: :show
resources :products
root to: 'products#index'
get ':id', to: 'pages#show', as: :page
```

I know there have been some updates on the way that rails generates scaffolds but I just can;t work out what needs to change to make this work? I'm getting errors thrown up both the routes, but was previously getting an error with  `@page = Page.find_by_permalink!(params[:id])`as well. It was saying that the method was missing but I couldn't see how. I also know I could use something like refinerycms but I really want to try and learn this stuff so any help much appreciated!

ERRORS FROM ROUTES:

```
Invalid route name, already in use: 'page' You may have defined two routes with the same name using the `:as` option, or you may be overriding a route already defined by a resource with the same naming. For the latter, you can restrict the routes created with `resources` as explained here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#restricting-the-routes-created
```

FULL TRACE:

```
ctionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:430:in `add_route'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1489:in `add_route'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1466:in `decomposed_match'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1447:in `block in match'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1437:in `each'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:1437:in `match'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:630:in `map_method'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/mapper.rb:591:in `get'
config/routes.rb:5:in `block in <top (required)>'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `instance_exec'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:337:in `eval_block'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:315:in `draw'
config/routes.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `block in load'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:232:in `load_dependency'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:241:in `load'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `block in load_paths'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `each'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:40:in `load_paths'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:16:in `reload!'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:26:in `block in updater'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/file_update_checker.rb:75:in `execute'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/application/routes_reloader.rb:7:in `execute'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:83:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Finisher>'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:438:in `instance_exec'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:438:in `block in make_lambda'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:184:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:184:in `block in simple'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `block in simple'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:185:in `block in simple'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:86:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:83:in `prepare!'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:71:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:76:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (4.1.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:26:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.1.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:514:in `call'
railties (4.1.5) lib/rails/application.rb:144:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.5.2) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.1/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
This error occurred while loading the following files:
   /home/ubuntu/workspace/traditional_cleaning/config/routes.rb
```

Comment: Can you actually show us the errors please? :)

Comment: Also - you might want to know that in the latest Rails, the dynamically-named find_by_X methods are deprecated...  replace them with: `Page.find_by!(permalink: params[:id])`

Comment: Thanks Taryn. Makes sense, I also noticed (in comparison with the screencast) that the scaffold generated was also missing a fair bit of code in the controller and it was confusing as to where to put the permalink? In the routes its saying that I've repeated pages too many times?

Comment: Yeah, not surprised... a lot has changed since Sep 02, 2012 :)

Comment: So... if you can edit your question and add the current set of errors (preferably including the stacktrace dumped into the server-logs) then we can help you solve this one :)

Comment: Great will do hang on

Comment: It may be worth to also run `rake routes` and have a look at what's generated by your `routes.rb` file. You might find something there to help you get de-confused.